Exporting ArcGIS Pro map to interactive PDF while setting Model Tree labels
I need to export (share) an interactive PDF map from ArcGIS Pro 3.3.1 and set each feature layer's Model Tree labels.  The basic creation of the interactive PDF is straight-forward by choosing "PDF Layers and Feature Attributes" when setting up the Export Map parameters, then doing the export.
Once the PDF is created and opened in Acrobat Reader, open the Model Tree viewer and see each feature layer listed, with each of its features listed below.  Each feature has a "label", which appears to be from one of the layer's attribute fields.
How do I tell ArcGIS Pro and/or the Export Maps function, for each feature layer, which attribute field (or expression) to use as the Model Tree label for the layer's features?
I have searched within ArcGIS Pro and with Google, to no avail.

The nit-picking word police have had their way with this question.  How about you spend that energy to instead do something useful, like answering the question?!

I think this is controlled by the Display setting of the layer. If you go to layer's properties and select the Display tab, you will be given Display field option. This will control what is published in the PDF's object tree labels (same behaviour for the KMLs as well). There is an option to create expression for the display fields, but it does not carry field information across the PDF, it reverts back to OID or default display field.
